biblatex, biber and comments in bib files
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear,backref]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{bibgraf.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{tao06:_global}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

with the bibfile (and a comment that causes problems using biber)
@Comment interesting
@Article{tao06:_global,
title        = {{Global behaviour of nonlinear dispersive and wave
              equations}},
author       = {Tao, T.},
journal      = {Current Developments in Mathematics},
year         = 2006,
archiveprefix= {arXiv},
arxivid      = {arXiv:math/0608293v1},
doi          = {10.4310/CDM.2006.v2006.n1.a5},
eprint       = {0608293v1},
issn         = 10896384,
primaryclass = {arXiv:math} 
}

When running biber (which works if the .bib file does not contain a comment) I obtain:
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bibgraf.bib'
ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: 
/tmp/biber_tmp_YtdQ/4967d2d2c16e06d6d91c1aa8344fd2f2_20721.utf8, line 1, syntax 
error: found "interesting", expected one of: start of entry ("{" or "(") or quoted 
string ({...} or "...")
INFO - ERRORS: 1

What do I miss here?

You can use latex comments with % and even without this symbol, and simply use:
interesting

Although in this case  biber will warn that you left "11 characters of junk seen at toplevel", but will end without a fatal error.
The syntax @Comment is also correct but, as biber said,  expected one start of entry,  {  or " to quote the comment  in this way: {...} or in this way: "...". Therefore, it also work:
@Comment{interesting}

And it is better, because a frequent problem is that the references could have many percentage symbols, and then a search and replace from % to `%"  will solve the break fields because the unwanted comments, but biber will warn you that you left "13 characters of junk seen at toplevel" that is not very serious, but annoying. Anothe advantage is that you can locate more easily the comments, using grep, for example.
Maybe for this, some programs like kbibtex change the latex comments into bibtex comments with arroba automatically.

One shouldn't use @-style comments like this:
@Comment interesting

@ is reserved to identify database entries (like article, book, ...). Instead, use the default %-style:
%Comment interesting

